# Как добавлять атрибуты к <line> через JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно добавить атрибуты `х1`, `у1`, `х2` и `у2` к `<line>` через JavaScript.
Так не работает:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   let id_num = 0;


   let nLine = document.createElement("line");

   nLine.id = id_num + "line";
   nLine.x1 = 1;
   nLine.y1 = 1;
   nLine.x2 = 2;
   nLine.y2 = 2;


   document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(nLine);

   id_num++;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `setAttribute`

```
   nLine.setAttribute('id', id_num + 'line');
   nLine.setAttribute('x1', 1);
   nLine.setAttribute('y1', 1);
   
   nLine.setAttribute('x2', 2);
   nLine.setAttribute('y2', 2);
```